Blazer Server: Trying to call a .net method from JavaScript using window,DotNet always give the error 'No call dispatcher has been set'
I am trying to call a .net method from some JavaScript in my Blazer server application, following this documentation but I always get No call dispatcher has been set.
I want to have the .net methods in a service that is always there, NOT a component (I find the Blazer components always seem to dispose of themselves). For example, I will use it for logging.
I have declared this (everything static)....
namespace MyNamespace.Utility
{
  public static class JsHelperService
  {
    static JsHelperService()
    {
      var i = 0; // just for testing with breakpoint
    }

    // Call from program.cs to make sure class is instantiated
    public static void Init()
    {
    }

    [JSInvokable("WriteInfo")]
    public static void WriteInfo(string message)
    {
      Logger.Instance.WriteInfo(message);
    }
  }
}

Then in JavaScript I have
function setupLogging() {
    debugger; // just while debugging       
    window.dotnetLogger = window.dotnetLogger || {};
    window.dotnetLogger.writeInfo = function (message) {
        window.DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('MyNamespace.JsHelperService', 'WriteInfo');
    };   
}

I then call setupLogging() to set this up.
When I debug, all seems to be there, ie window.DotNet is available etc.
However, when I then call window.dotnetLogger.writeInfo from elsewhere in JavaScript, I can see the function is called, but as soon as it executes the
window.DotNet.invokeMethodAsync

I get the error
Uncaught Error: No call dispatcher has been set.
  at v (blazor.web.js:1:1776)
  at e.invokeMethodAsync (blazor.web.js:1:2231)
  at window.dotnetLogger.writeInfo (site.js:41:18)

I was not sure what to use for the namespace, we the doco does not even have an example, so I tried both MyNamespace.JsHelperService and just MyNamespace but neither made a difference.
Would anyone know how I can fix this?

From the error it seems like you are invoking the change event before blazor is fully initialized.

@JasonPan - not in my case. I tested logging well after the app was up and running. It always reaches JS code, but as soon as I call window.DotNet.invokeMethodAsync I get the error

Hi peterc, I shared my test steps below, please kindly check it, many thanks

Here is my working sample.
JsHelperService.cs
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace BlazorApp1.Utility
{
    public static class JsHelperService
    {
        public static void Init()
        {
        }

        [JSInvokable("WriteInfo")]
        public static void WriteInfo(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[Info]: {message}");
        }
    }
}

Register it
var app = builder.Build();

// Register it.
JsHelperService.Init();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();

Counter.razor
@page "/counter"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setupLogging");

            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("window.dotnetLogger.writeInfo", "this is test message.");
        }
    }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}

site.js
document.addEventListener('blazor:loaded', function () {
    setupLogging();
});

function setupLogging() {
    window.dotnetLogger = window.dotnetLogger || {};
    window.dotnetLogger.writeInfo = function (message) {
        window.DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('BlazorApp1', 'WriteInfo', message);
    };
}


Test Result


Hmm, really not sure why yours works and mine does not. As you have above, I added my await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setupLogging"); to one of my components and also added the blazor:loaded listener, but my blazor:loaded handler is just never called. However the setupLogging is called and hooks up the object on the window. However I still get the same error when I try and call the writeInfo. I am using server side (only) Blazer, could this be a difference?

Hi @peterc Which template you are using Blazor Server App or Blazor Web App ? If blazor server app, try to create a new one and use my test code, many thanks

Thanks @Jason but I didn't actually create the project I have come into an exiting project help do some of the work, so I cant change it (largish code base). I. From what I understand it is server side rending only, It links in _framework/blazor.web.js if that is of any use. Perhaps this is not possible in this variant of project, though I don't see any limitations mentioned in the doco. The error message is quite cryptic.
